# Xamarin.Forms: Merge one Image into another (Android Project)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have one "starBorder.png" image and I merge it to "start.png" with a simple Scale animation to simulate adding some item to a Favourites list:

```
await imageFavourite.ScaleTo(scaleMin, 75);
await imageFavourite.ScaleTo(scaleNormal, 75);
imageFavourite.Source = "star.png";
```

On my iOS project it looks perfectly, however, on my Android project it goes blank a short time between the images swap. I guess the problem is loading the second image.

Is there any way to optimize this "animation" merging images on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) library on NuGet which acts as a drop-in replacement for Image. They have a `Preload()` method you could use as seen in their source [here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/source/FFImageLoading.Droid/TaskParameterExtensions.cs).